# C# Replace exact part of string containing special characters

Tags: c#, special-characters, string.format

I am trying to replace part of a string with the following code:

```
public static string SafeReplace(this string input, string find, string replace, bool matchWholeWord)
{

        string textToFind = matchWholeWord ? string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", find) : find;
        return Regex.Replace(input, textToFind, replace);

}
```

But when I have special characters inside the string this does not work. I've tried escaping the characters but with no luck...

Here is an example, I have the following string:

```
Peter[='111222'] + APeter[='111222']
```

I want to replace `Peter[='111222']` with `@` so the result should be: 
`@ + APeter[='111222']`. With the given code, the string remains as it is and nothing changes.

Please note that I might have many different situations with other special characters like `Steven.intr[A:B;>1], Sssdf.len, asd.ind` and etc. so in my case I need to find exact matches with different formats.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post few more examples

Comment: sure: George[=1],QC.ind, asd.len. It should work with strings which do not include special characters as well. Here is other example of string that I need to replace: "asd.len + hasd.len" --> replace "asd.len" --> result: "@ + hasd.len".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of matching to word boundaries, match to whitespace and/or beggining/end of string. This will work for non-alphanumeric.

Also, you need to escape your string, and remove the word boundaries (in my case, whitespace and/or begin/end of line) from the replace: you can do that using lookahead/lookbehind.

So all this said:

```
public static string SafeReplace(this string input, string find, string replace, bool matchWholeWord)
{
    string textToFind = matchWholeWord ? string.Format(@"(?<=^|\s){0}(?=$|\s)", Regex.Escape(find)) : Regex.Escape(find);
    return Regex.Replace(input, textToFind, replace);
}
```

[I've made a demonstrating fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I7t3Er)

Comment: Hi, Please see an example where your code is not working: [fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1UAB3Q)

Comment: I somehow messed up before posting and removed the "beggining of string" from the regex... the correct `textToFind` should be `(?<=^|\s){0}(?=[$|\s])`. I'm editing and changing the fiddle

Comment: There you go, sorry, it was just a tiny typo (the explanation was correct though). You may want to add anything that you consider a "word boundary" (maybe commas too?) to both sides of the `{0}`

Comment: @Venco you have a problem with your specifications of the problem. What defines what "matchWholeWords" means? In this fiddle, you mean you want "Q5" to be replaced, but in "Q5.", the "." should be a word boundary, but the "h" in "hQ5" isn't. What says that "h" is not a word boundary, but "." is? The fact that it is alphanumeric? Because then that wouldn't match with other examples you want. Check your specifications and make sure everything is clear and unmistakable

Comment: The "fix" for the `Q5.` example is easy, as I said in my other comments, add what you consider a "word boundary" to the regex. In this case: `(?<=^|\s|\.)` and `(?=[$|\s|\.])`... if you also want commas, `(?<=^|\s|\.|\,)` and `(?=[$|\s|\.|\,])`, etc. but you need to have a clear definition of what you want as a word boundary, and make sure it matches all your possible replacements (or non-replacements)

Comment: sorry, it seems that you've opened wrong example. Indeed "." should not be a boundary. Please use this one: [fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IOMvgm)

Comment: @Venco same thing there... add the `+` and `=` characters to possible word boundaries: [check it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8T2JB2) (btw, I also had incorrect brackets on the lookahead... I've removed them). Basically, make sure whatever you think is a word boundary and defines what should or should not be determinant that a word is "a matched word" is in the regex that separates the string

Comment: Thank you! The suggested code works for me, I will just add spaces around all operators and we are good :) Thank you for the help and responsiveness here!